# Replacing http request-response structure with a platform event driven solution

Tags: rest-api, servicecloud

We have a lot of long running callouts to provide live data from physical devices to our users. Due mainly to other issues, the org is running in to concurrent request limits. However I am interested in changing the http request-response structure of our callouts to a platform event driven solution where requests are fire and forget and responses are platform events created via api.
I have looked through the documenation but I am still wondering if there is any reason why this would not be a good idea?
Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Considerations for Publishing and Subscribing to Platform Events with Apex and APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_api_considerations.htm) covers a wide set of factors. One area to focus on is the [Platform Event Allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm), essentially the upper limits depending on org edition.

We use them in the way you are considering with Lightning Web Components (LWCs) receiving them via [lightning-emp-api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation).

Comment: @Kieth C thank you. I had look through this, particularly the allocations. I was not sure though what was the difference between the limit for processes subscribed and active processes subscribed. We too are using it with LWCs. Would every instance of a subscribed LWC be an active process subscription?

Comment: Hi @Dane, I assume so but am not sure.

Comment: thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: This is the feature that can allow to use it more widely -- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_platform_events_filtering_beta.htm&type=5&release=236, but it is still in Beta

Comment: @kurunve Also very useful. Thank you.